# Secured PDF Content

Tags: google-search-appliance

When GSA crawls asp, aspx pages, I am seeing that it is sending cookies along with the request.  But when the GSA crawls PDF’s, we don’t see any cookies being sent with the request.  Is there something inherent in the GSA that would prevent sending cookies to PDF’s?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything different in this regard.  However, possible reasons for the cookies not being sent are:

**http versus https.**  The cookie are set as secure and therefore not sent on an http request
**path and domain scoping.** The cookie's scope is not allowing it to be sent where the pdf's are located.